# Error when communicating with the native messaging host- Java

Tags: javascript, java, google-chrome-extension

So I am learning about Native messaging with chrome extension using Java. I got the following error while testing the app:  Error when communicating with the native messaging host.
I wasn't sure what was the problem or how can I track the error.
**Here's my checker.bat file:**

```
@echo off
javac Test.java
java Test
```

**Here's manifest.JSON:**

```
{
  "name": "host1",

  "description": "Test",
  "path": "checker.bat",
  "type": "stdio",
  "allowed_origins": [
    "chrome-extension://eogmgkhgmdjkdhkfacckkjhmffnniiab/"
  ]
}
```

public class Test {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Test t=new Test();
    String to_process_string="";
    try {
        to_process_string = t.readMessage(System.in);
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    String final_output;
    String output=to_process_string+" recieved";
    final_output="{\"m\":\""+output+"\"}";
    try {
        t.sendMessage(final_output);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
private String readMessage(InputStream in) throws IOException {
    byte[] b = new byte[4];
    in.read(b);

    int size = getInt(b);

    if (size == 0) {
      throw new InterruptedIOException("Blocked communication");
    }

    b = new byte[size];
    in.read(b);

    return new String(b, "UTF-8");
  }

  private void sendMessage(String message) throws IOException {
    System.out.write(getBytes(message.length()));
    System.out.write(message.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    System.out.flush();
  }

  public int getInt(byte[] bytes) {
    return (bytes[3] << 24) & 0xff000000 | (bytes[2] << 16) & 0x00ff0000
        | (bytes[1] << 8) & 0x0000ff00 | (bytes[0] << 0) & 0x000000ff;
  }

  public byte[] getBytes(int length) {
    byte[] bytes = new byte[4];
    bytes[0] = (byte) (length & 0xFF);
    bytes[1] = (byte) ((length >> 8) & 0xFF);
    bytes[2] = (byte) ((length >> 16) & 0xFF);
    bytes[3] = (byte) ((length >> 24) & 0xFF);
    return bytes;
  }
```

}
I am not pretty sure what might be the problem can u help me? 
Note: this is how I registered the key : REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Google\Chrome\NativeMessagingHosts\host1" /ve /t REG_SZ /d "C:\Users\Rex\Desktop\TestNative\Host\manifest.json" /f

**EDIT:** So i have tried to the JSON format as WoXxo suggested in comments but it still gave me the same error. I decided to log problems into the file but nothing was logging so I decided to connect keep the main function empty and see if it was a problem with the code or a connection problem. It turned out that it kept giving me the same results. Any idea what might be the problem?

Comment: `"{\"m\":}"+output;` will produce an invalid JSON object: you need to move `}` after `output`.

Comment: @wOxxOm I have corrected it but it still gives me the same error

Comment: Ah, `output` also needs escaped quotes: `"{\"m\":\""+output+"\"}";`

Comment: @wOxxOm sorry to bother you but still getting the same error

Comment: I guess there are embedded quotes in the received string which you need to remove first. Actually don't concatenate strings manually. It's best to use JSON parsing when receiving and JSON serialization when sending.

Comment: @wOxxOm Can u please read the edit on the question?